# Identify horizontal regions in noisy graph

Tags: python, graph, calculus

I have a bunch of noisy data.
[image]
I need be able to find the points where the increase in y begins and ends. Visually it's pretty obvious, but i've been having a hard time trying to come up with an algorithm that would be consistent and accurate. 
I tried getting the slope directly (just as a difference of neighboring points):
[image]
But here still, i'm not sure how to properly identify the beginning and end of a step. I tried just going off of the magnitude of difference between points, but I get either a lot of false positives (like in that very noisy spike in the second graph), or I miss the very small steps (like the first and third). I also tried going in steps of ten points, calculating a best fit line, and the MSE, and when the MSE gets about a certain threshold, i would consider that a corner in the graph. For example, for 10 points in the somewhat horizontal line, the MSE for the best fit line would be small, but for 9 points and 1 that is at the beginning of the incline, the MSE is much larger.
I thought about trying to convert it into a step graph, but I'm not sure how to do it, plus i feel like i might end up with just one point where the graph goes from low to high, rather than two points, one for when it starts increasing, and another when it stops.
Does anyone have any ideas on how one might go about doing this?

Comment: You're looking for transitions from low gradient (flat curve) to high gradient - i.e. the start of a step, and the reverse is the end of a step. Such changes in gradient will probably be most obvious by looking at a second derivative curve - and can then set a positive and negative threshold for either side of a step. You could try the five-point stencil second derivative given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-point_stencil  NB: you'll loose the first two and last two data points, and it assumes a constant sampling interval.

Comment: You are fighting [signal to noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) here. You could try to filter out some of that noise, by using convolutions with e.g. a gaussian kernel, or look into [smoothing algorithms](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html).

Comment: can you share data producing your first plot?